# How to separately handling MouseClick and MouseDoubleClick event on ChartControl

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, devexpress, mouseevent

I'm implementing a module which needs to handle both `MouseClick` and `MouseDoubleClick` on a `ChartControl` of `DevExpress`. The version that I'm using is v12.2.

When I double click on that chart, both events are fired. I'd like (and I think that it must be) it just fires one event, in this case, `MouseDoubleClick`.

So, anyone know how to fix that problem?

***What's I've tried:***

- Handle `MouseClick` or `Click` event and see `MouseEventArgs#Clicks` property. But it's always 1.

***What's I'm using:***

- Declare a boolean variable to tell if `MouseDoubleClick` is fired. On `MouseClick` handling, just waiting for a moment, then do the codes if that variable does not turn on. I think this is a bad implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You need a time machine to see the difference between the two.  Inevitably a double-click starts with a single click, you always see the first click first.

You can get a time machine that sees the future by using a timer that delays the past.  Set its interval to SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime + 16 and start it in the Click event, stop it in the DoubleClick event.  If the Tick event fires then it was a single click.

That works, but do note that the delayed response to a single click is fairly annoying.  Best not to annoy your user with a user interface like that.

Comment: I like your final sentence. Thanks. It's not my design, I just implement it.